# MYSQL Inner join for three to four tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Please I need to figure out what I am doing wrong. I created this inner join code for mysql. it works but it gives me repeated values like repeating a particular row twice or categoryid twice. each of the tables(users,paymentnotification,monthlyreturns) has the categoryid used to check and display the username(users.pname) from the user table, then check and display those that have made payment from the monthly returns and payment table using the categoryid.

```
$r="SELECT monthlyreturns.categoryid, monthlyreturns.month, monthlyreturns.quarter, monthlyreturns.year,paymentnotification.amount, users.pname, monthlyreturns.ototal, paymentnotification.payee, status
FROM paymentnotification 
INNER JOIN (monthlyreturns INNER JOIN users ON monthlyreturns.categoryid=users.categoryid) 
ON monthlyreturns.categoryid=paymentnotification.categoryid 
ORDER BY monthlyreturns.categoryid DESC";
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your tables on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: A little bit of context on tables would have been great. Anyways, you can use 'DISTINCT' to filter out duplicates.

Comment: Is categoryid unique in each table?  If not, and any of the tables contains multiple rows with the same categoryid value, then the output will include multiple entries.  You then need to filter these down either by using `DISTINCT`, as Pankaj Gadge's answer below, or using group functions depending on the fields you require to reduce it to one row per columnid.

Comment: I just edited the post for better understanding. thanks guys

Comment: tried the group but it just filters it to two rows

Comment: @BeNdErR, Here are the identifiers #!2/4536d - users
#!2/f7d6a - monthlyreturns
#!2/548796 - paymentnotification

Comment: the sqlfiddle. Here are the identifiers for my tables #!2/4536d - users #!2/f7d6a - monthlyreturns #!2/548796 - paymentnotification

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I think the query you want is more like this:

```
SELECT b.categoryid, b.month, b.quarter, b.year, a.amount, c.pname, b.ototal, a.payee, status
FROM paymentnotification a
INNER JOIN monthlyreturns b
   ON a.categoryid = b.categoryid
INNER JOIN users c
   ON b.categoryid = c.categoryid
ORDER BY b.categoryid DESC
```

The way you are doing the correlations doesn't seem clear and may cause problems. Try this one out and see what happens. If its still doing duplicates, perhaps the nature of the data require further filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, you are not joining your tables properly. Try joining one at a time

```
SELECT DISTINCT monthlyreturns.categoryid, monthlyreturns.month, monthlyreturns.quarter, monthlyreturns.year,paym entnotification.amount, users.pname, monthlyreturns.ototal, paymentnotification.payee, status
FROM paymentnotification 
INNER JOIN monthlyreturns
ON paymentnotification.categoryid = monthlyreturns.categoryid
INNER JOIN users 
ON monthlyreturns.categoryid = users.categoryid
ORDER BY monthlyreturns.categoryid DESC
```

Comment: my tables are joined correctly cos I tried yours n it gave me the same result

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah Well then its probably because you are joining on something that is not unique. Try adding a `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: Say I join `t1.id = t2.foreign_key WHERE t1.id = 5`. If `id` is is unique and has `5`, but `foreign_key` has 4 values that are `5`, you will get 4 rows for each foreign_key that joins. You can use `DISTINCT`, as I did in my edit, but if you are SELECTing more fields that are unique (not duplicates) within these 4 rows, you will get those rows are well..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem.. I get 4 result rows: check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/165a22/5

this is the query I used:

```
SELECT m.categoryid, m.month, m.quarter, m.year,p.amount, u.pname, m.ototal, p.payee, m.status
FROM paymentnotification p JOIN monthlyreturns m ON p.categoryid = m.categoryid
JOIN users u ON u.categoryid = m.categoryid
ORDER BY m.categoryid DESC
```

there are no duplicated rows, just "unique" rows if you consider every column you choose.

Hope it helps

Comment: ,thank you for your help.the paymentnotification table has 'a0303' twice in the row and not four time. the monthlyreturns table is used to get the amount  'ototal column' while the users table is meant for getting the name(pname). Anticipating your response and sorry for the mixed up in my presentation using sqlfiddle. I am newbie and just learnt how to use it yesterday when you mentioned it.

Comment: that behaviour (four a0303 rows) is normal, because the JOIN between your tables find multiple values associated to the same id in the join path. If you want to get ONLY ONE row with id = a0303, I think you need to insert a GROUP BY clause (for example this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/165a22/14) but you'll probably loose some informations you need.

Comment: sorry to bother you much on this. I have tried the group by before now and the result you have in the sqlfiddle is what it gave me which is not getting me what I want. It knocks out other important rows like a row with the same id but different data. Is there a way I can make it show the rows needed.

Comment: can you re-tell me exactly what you need as output? which columns do you need in the resultset? how will you use the data you'll get from the query?

Comment: what I want to achieve is to display a record set which pulls e.g. the username(pname column),etc of a categoryid in monthlyreturns table from the users table  which also a column named categoryid.It then displays the record set based on the categoryid that are in the paymentnotification table alongside other data drawn from the other tables. thank you for your help so far.

Comment: as Shredder said in another comment (response above), "if you are SELECTing more fields that are unique (not duplicates) within these 4 rows, you will get those rows are well". Google how JOIN works in sql, you'll get a better idea on how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

SELECT M.categoryid, M.month,  M.quarter,  M.year, M.ototal,

```
   P.amount, P.payee, P.status,

   U.pname
```

FROM paymentnotification AS P

INNER JOIN monthlyreturns AS M ON P.categoryid = M.categoryid

INNER JOIN users AS U ON M.categoryid = U.categoryid

ORDER BY M.categoryid DESC